# Incomplete filling when upsampling with `agg` for multiple columns (pandas resample)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna, pandas-resample

I found this behavior of `resample` to be confusing after working on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65111602/13386979).  Here are some time series data at 5 minute intervals but with missing rows (code to construct at end):

```
                    user  value  total
2020-01-01 09:00:00  fred      1      1
2020-01-01 09:05:00  fred     13      1
2020-01-01 09:15:00  fred     27      3
2020-01-01 09:30:00  fred     40     12
2020-01-01 09:35:00  fred     15     12
2020-01-01 10:00:00  fred     19     16
```

I want to fill in the missing times using different methods for each column to fill missing data.  For `user` and `total`, I want to to a forward fill, while for `value` I want to fill in with zeroes.

One approach I found was to `resample`, and then fill in the missing data after the fact:

```
resampled = df.resample('5T').asfreq()
resampled['user'].ffill(inplace=True)
resampled['total'].ffill(inplace=True)
resampled['value'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Which gives correct expected output:

```
                     user  value  total
2020-01-01 09:00:00  fred    1.0    1.0
2020-01-01 09:05:00  fred   13.0    1.0
2020-01-01 09:10:00  fred    0.0    1.0
2020-01-01 09:15:00  fred   27.0    3.0
2020-01-01 09:20:00  fred    0.0    3.0
2020-01-01 09:25:00  fred    0.0    3.0
2020-01-01 09:30:00  fred   40.0   12.0
2020-01-01 09:35:00  fred   15.0   12.0
2020-01-01 09:40:00  fred    0.0   12.0
2020-01-01 09:45:00  fred    0.0   12.0
2020-01-01 09:50:00  fred    0.0   12.0
2020-01-01 09:55:00  fred    0.0   12.0
2020-01-01 10:00:00  fred   19.0   16.0
```

I thought one would be able to use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) to specify what to do by column.  I try to do the following:

```
resampled = df.resample('5T').agg({'user':'ffill',
                                   'value':'sum',
                                   'total':'ffill'})
```

I find this to be more clear and simpler, **but** it doesn't give the expected output.  The sum works, but the forward fill does not:

```
                     user  value  total
2020-01-01 09:00:00  fred      1    1.0
2020-01-01 09:05:00  fred     13    1.0
2020-01-01 09:10:00   NaN      0    NaN
2020-01-01 09:15:00  fred     27    3.0
2020-01-01 09:20:00   NaN      0    NaN
2020-01-01 09:25:00   NaN      0    NaN
2020-01-01 09:30:00  fred     40   12.0
2020-01-01 09:35:00  fred     15   12.0
2020-01-01 09:40:00   NaN      0    NaN
2020-01-01 09:45:00   NaN      0    NaN
2020-01-01 09:50:00   NaN      0    NaN
2020-01-01 09:55:00   NaN      0    NaN
2020-01-01 10:00:00  fred     19   16.0
```

**Can someone explain this output, and if there is a way to achieve the expected output using `agg`**?  It seems odd that the forward fill doesn't work here, but if I were to just do `resampled = df.resample('5T').ffill()`, that would work for every column (but is undesired here as it would do so for the `value` column as well).  The closest I have come is to individually run resampling for each column and apply the function I want:

```
resampled = pd.DataFrame()

d = {'user':'ffill',
     'value':'sum',
     'total':'ffill'}

for k, v in d.items():
    resampled[k] = df[k].resample('5T').apply(v)
```

This works, but feels silly given that it adds extra iteration and uses the dictionary I am trying to pass to `agg`!  I have looked a few posts on `agg` and `apply` but can't seem to explain what is happening here:

- [Losing String column when using resample and aggregation with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767650/losing-string-column-when-using-resample-and-aggregation-with-pandas)
- [resample multiple columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629100/resample-multiple-columns-with-pandas)
- [pandas groupby with agg not working on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210028/pandas-groupby-with-agg-not-working-on-multiple-columns)
- [Pandas named aggregation not working with resample agg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788893/pandas-named-aggregation-not-working-with-resample-agg)

I have also tried using `groupby` with a `pd.Grouper` and using the `pd.NamedAgg` class, with no luck.

---

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['01-01-2020 9:00', '01-01-2020 9:05', '01-01-2020 9:15',
         '01-01-2020 9:30', '01-01-2020 9:35', '01-01-2020 10:00']
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)

df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['fred']*len(dates),
                   'value':[1,13,27,40,15,19],
                   'total':[1,1,3,12,12,16]},
                  index=dates)
```

Comment: Sum is an aggregating function, ffill is not

Comment: @DaniMesejo I guess I'm not clear on what the difference is.  B/c in my loop resampling, you can still do `resampled[k] = df[k].resample('5T').agg(v)` (instead of `apply`).  And if you only wanted to do `ffill` (or any other named aggregation function it seems), doing `df.resample('5T').agg('ffill')` works as expected for all columns.